# How to get filtered nodes in Datatables

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, datatables

I wish to get just the rows that are filtered on with datatables:

```
  $("#selectAllLocations").click ->
    filtered = $("#restaurantLocations").dataTable().fnGetFilteredNodes()
    filtered.$("tr").addClass "Selected"
```

However, calling this function calls errors as:

[image]

on the line `$("#restaurantLocations").dataTable().fnGetFilteredNodes()`

How can I call the function fnGetFilteredNodes() to do further operation on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call jQuery `(or $)` as a method of jQuery `(or $)`... Try using the 'find()' method instead, which is generically used for filtering.

```
  $("#selectAllLocations").click ->
    filtered = $("#restaurantLocations").dataTable().fnGetFilteredNodes()
    filtered.find("tr").addClass "Selected"
```

Comment: It appears that `.fnGetFilteredNodes()` is no longer prefernetial. The apparently use: `.$('tr', {"filter":"applied"}).addClass "selected"` instead. You can write up that answer and it is correct, I have tested it

Comment: It's quite different from what I've written, I couldn't change it to that. But what I've written works for arrays (as `filtered` is supposed to be) beautifully.

Comment: I was not able to get `.fnGetFilteredNodes()` to run, `.fnGetNodes()` works just fine but running `.fnGetFilteredNodes()`  yields the errors above